# When (if ever) C++ concepts must be “decayed”, do it at concept definition or at “requires”?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-traits, c++-concepts

Imagine I have a concept that checks for some trait of a member type, e.g. its `integral`ness. In anticipation of what is to come, let me define it in two ways:

```c++
namespace decayedAtConcept {
  template <typename T>
  concept hasIntegralMemberType = std::integral<typename std::decay_t<T>::MemberType>;
}

namespace notDecayedAtConcept {
  template <typename T>
  concept hasIntegralMemberType = std::integral<typename T::MemberType>;
}
```

With the following definitions

```c++
struct HasIntegralMemberType {using MemberType = int;};

struct HasNonintegralMemberType {using MemberType = double;};

struct DoesNotHaveMemberType {};
```

and the following function declarations

```c++
void usesIntegralMemberType1 (decayedAtConcept::hasIntegralMemberType auto&&);

void usesIntegralMemberType2 (notDecayedAtConcept::hasIntegralMemberType auto&&);

template <typename T> requires notDecayedAtConcept::hasIntegralMemberType<std::decay_t<T>>
void usesIntegralMemberType3 (T&&);
```

in effect, a client can try to use this library in the following way:

```c++
void client () { 
  HasIntegralMemberType h;

  usesIntegralMemberType1(HasIntegralMemberType{});
  usesIntegralMemberType1(h); // OK
  //usesIntegralMemberType1(HasNonintegralMemberType{}); //note: constraints not satisfied
  //usesIntegralMemberType1(DoesNotHaveMemberType{});    //note: constraints not satisfied

  usesIntegralMemberType2(HasIntegralMemberType{});
  //usesIntegralMemberType2(h); //error: ‘HasIntegralMemberType&’ is not a class, struct, or union type

  usesIntegralMemberType3(HasIntegralMemberType{});
  usesIntegralMemberType3(h); // OK again
}
```

---

The `note`s just demonstrate that the concept works as expected in `usesIntegralMemberType1`. My question is related to the `error` caused by the naive usage of the `notDecayedAtConcept` in `usesIntegralMemberType2`.

Apparently, the `notDecayedAtConcept` version of the concept is less convenient to use because any time it is used with a universal reference, it needs to be decayed in a `requires` clause as in `usesIntegralMemberType3`. We even lose the syntactic sugar we had in defining the constrained template parameter in `usesIntegralMemberType1`.

---

**And now the question:** are there already some guidelines which of the two strategies to use in such a situation? Or, is there any other, more transparent/convenient solution?

Comment: It seems self-evident: if you expect your concept to be useful as a placeholder type then it needs to expect the type to be possibly be a reference. Not every concept is sensible as a placeholder so I'm not sure there's an answer that applies to every concept.